# İnternal and hold out test for shap

Tags: predictive-modeling, feature-extraction, model-evaluations, explainable-ai, shap

There is an internal test set and a hold out test set. I explain the model with Shap library. Should I use the internal test set or the external test set? What should I do if there is a difference?